# Is it possible for a child div to overflow and affect the positioning of divs outside its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

for context I am building a day view calendar and I have mapped each hour in the day out while filtering my events to see if they should be rendered in that hourblock

my issue is that long events which span multiple hours are positioned behind other events and i would like to find a way for the overflow content to push the next events div over to the right as if it was flexed in the same container.

[Ideally the pink "event" should sit to the right of the blue one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NDNc.png)

currently the future event divs just ignore the previous events overflow

no Jquery and if this one thing can be solved with css that is ideal. doing math with JS is probably possible but could be less reliable / buggy

Thanks in advance guys :)

**CalendarHour.tsx**

```
    hourBlock: {
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100%',
      height: '64px',
      position: 'relative',
    },
    time: {
      fontSize: FONT_SIZE_SMALL,
      color: PLAIN_GREY,
      marginRight: '30px',
      lineHeight: '0',
    },
    content: {
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100%',
      borderTop: `1px solid ${PLAIN_GREY}`,
    },
    line: {
      height: '1px',
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: LIGHT_GREY,
      margin: 'auto',
    },


{[...Array(hoursInDay)].map((e, index) => (
        <div className={classes.hourBlock} key={e}>
          <div className={classes.time}>{renderTime(index)}</div>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            {events
              ?.filter((e) => format(new Date(e.start.toString()), 'HH') == renderHour(index))
              .map((e) => (
                <CalendarEventItem key={e.id} event={e} />
              ))}
            <div className={classes.line} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

**CalendarEventItem.tsx**

```
    eventItemWrapper: {
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100%',
      borderLeft: `2px solid ${color}`,
      backgroundColor: WHITE,
      fontSize: '12px',
      marginRight: '5px',
      height,
      position: 'relative',
    },
    title: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      marginRight: '5px',
    },
    detailsWrapper: {
      backgroundColor: fadedColor,
      width: '100%',
      paddingLeft: '4px',
    },
    details: {},


    <div className={classes.eventItemWrapper}>
      <div className={classes.detailsWrapper}>
        <div className={classes.title}>{event.name}</div>
        <div className={classes.details}>{eventDetails}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want an element to affect its parent siblings, you must not make it overflow, but let the container to adapt its width to the child element.

Comment: hey Cesare, the issue is more that i need child one to affect child 2 when both have different parents

so child 1 should push child 2 over

`<div className='parent1'>
     <div className='child1'/>
 </div>
<div className='parent2'>
     <div className='child2'/>
 </div>
`

Comment: I included a snippet, I think you won't be able to achieve what you want with CSS only, but you surely can use JS, as I showed in the example.

Comment: great snippet @CesarePolonara, thanks for doing that it taught me some things i didnt know. I ended up going the JS math way and creating an array of arrays to map out my calendar time slots and check if there are any conflicting events. I think the main answer to "can overflow affect divs outside its parent" is no as you stated at least not with CSS. its a shame because JS way was a ton of work

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet might help you, I included two examples, the one on the left uses a fixed size container, so when the child grows, it overflows, and the only way to make the child interact with other elements is through JS.

The second example on the right on the contrary uses containers with non fixed size, so they are free to grow/shrink when the children change their size, so the child can interact with other elements through its own parent.

```js
let height = 50;

btn.onclick = e => {
  height += 1
  child1.style.height = height + "px"
}

let height2 = 50;

btn2.onclick = e => {
  height2 += 1
  child3.style.height = height2 + "px"
}

// OBSERVER

const targetNode = child1

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationList, observer) {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === "style") {
      const child2Y = child2.getBoundingClientRect().y
      const child1Y = child1.getBoundingClientRect().y
      const child1Height = child1.getBoundingClientRect().height
      if (child1Y + child1Height >= child2Y) child2.style.transform = `translateY(${child1Y+child1Height - child2Y}px)`

    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.parent1 {
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#child2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#child3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#child4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="parent1">
    <div id="child1">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div id="child2">Child2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Enlarge Child 1</button>




<div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div id="child3">Child3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent4">
    <div id="child4">Child4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn2">Enlarge Child 3</button>
```